# Simplifying confluient hypergeometric functions

Tags: functions, special-functions, hypergeometric-function

I need to simplify the confulent hypergeometric function:

$U(x>1,1/2,y>0)$. I don't know if someone knows a simpler form ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no simpler form, the result can only be expressed in terms of [parabolic cylinder functions](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ParabolicCylinderFunction.html):
$$U\left(x,1/2,y\right)=2^x e^{y/2}D_{-2x}\left(\sqrt{2y}\right).$$

Comment: Is there some kind of book of database that you use to find these relations ?

Comment: @Nick Abramowitz-Stegun, or [DLMF](http://dlmf.nist.gov/13.6#iv). Btw you can also upvote an answer in addition to accepting it - of course, if you find it useful.

Comment: thanks, and vote well deserved! This DLMF, is it of the same kind as the NIST-book provided by cambridge ?

Comment: @Nick Yes, it is even possible that they have corrected some misprints in the online version.

Comment: It seems that using the "duplication formula" for gamma functions (with a variable change) and DLMF https://dlmf.nist.gov/13.4.E18; and then a reverse Mellin transform gives an answer.  Piecewise but simple algebra.

Comment: @rrogers What is this answer?

Comment: I tried and I apparently can only reach the above solution or the Modified Bessel function K_v () ; or the obvious M() combination DLMF https://dlmf.nist.gov/13.2.E42  Disappointing, the result from my previous comment was: in the Mellin transform domain $ \Gamma(2*s)/\Gamma(x+s)$.  The G function domain leads back to Modified Bessel; so the special value b=1/2 seems to be stuck in the Hypergeometric mode.